# callback function return return($var & 1)?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

I have read the PHP Manuel about [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
<?php
function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return($var & 1);
}

function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return(!($var & 1));
}

$array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
$array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

echo "Odd :\n";
print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));
echo "Even:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array2, "even"));
?>
```

Even I see the result here :

```
Odd :
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [c] => 3
    [e] => 5
)
Even:
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [2] => 8
    [4] => 10
    [6] => 12
)
```

But I did not understand about this line: `return($var & 1);` Could anyone explain me about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$var & 1` - is bitwise AND
it checks if `$var` is ODD value

```
0 & 0 = 0,
0 & 1 = 0,
1 & 0 = 0,
1 & 1 = 1
```

so, first callback function returns TRUE only if $var is ODD, and second - vise versa (! - is logical NOT).

Answer (score 5):

You know  `&&` is `AND`, but what you probably don't know is `&` is a *bit-wise* `AND`.

The `&` operator works at a bit level, it is bit-wise. You need to think in terms of the binary representations of the operands.

e.g.

> `710 & 210 =  1112 & 0102 = 0102 = 210`

For instance, the expression `$var & 1` is used to test if the least significant bit is `1` or `0`, odd or even respectively.

> `$var & 1`
>
> `010 & 110 =  0002 & 0012 = 0002 = 010 = false (even)`
>
> `110 & 110 =  0012 & 0012 = 0012 = 110 = true  (odd)`
>
> `210 & 110 =  0102 & 0012 = 0002 = 010 = false (even)`
>
> `310 & 110 =  0112 & 0012 = 0012 = 110 = true  (odd)`
>
> `410 & 210 =  1002 & 0012 = 0002 = 010 = false (even)`
>
> `and so on...`

Comment: so ($var & 1) compares $var to number 1 ?

Answer (score 4):

```
&
```

it's the bitwise operator. It does the AND with the corrispondent bit of `$var` and `1`

Basically it test the last bit of $var to see if the number is even or odd

Example with $var binary being 000110 and 1

```
000110 &
     1
------
     0
```

0 (false) in this case is returned so the number is even, and your function returns false accordingly

Comment: I understand it is AND. But how does ($var x & 1) determine whether is odd

Comment: It is AND, except it acts on each bit of the two numbers you compare individually (and returns an int), instead of the logical AND which acts on the two numbers as a whole (and returns a boolean).

Comment: @gilzero Picture binary numbers.. 0001 = 1 (odd), 0011 = 3 (odd), 0010 = 2 (even). See the pattern? If the first (right-most) bit is 1 then the number is ALWAYS odd. So the comparison is checking to see if that bit is true or not.. if it is then its odd otherwise even.

Comment: Is it a Arithmetic Operator or Comparison Operator?

Comment: @gilzero - neither.... it's a bitwise operator - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 2):

It is performing a bitwise AND with $var and 1. Since 1 only has the last bit set, `$var & 1` will only be true if the last bit is set in $var. And since even numbers never have the last bit set, if the AND is true the number must be odd.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is bitwise "and" operator. With 1, 3, 5 (and other odd numbers) `$var & 1` will result in "1", with 0, 2, 4 (and other even numbers) - in "0".

Answer (score 1):

An odd number has its zeroth ([least significant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit)) bit set to `1`:

```
           v
0 = 00000000b
1 = 00000001b
2 = 00000010b
3 = 00000011b
           ^
```

The expression `$var & 1` performs a [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_AND#AND) operation between $var and 1 (`1 = 00000001b`). So 
the expression will return:

- 1 when `$var` has its zeroth bit set to 1 (odd number)
- 0 when `$var` has its zeroth bit set to 0 (even number)

Answer (score 0):

& is a [bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) AND on $var.

If $var is a decimal 4, it's a binary 100. 100 & 1 is 100, because the right most digit is a 0 in $var - and 0 & 1 is 0, thus, 4 is even.

Answer (score 0):

it returns 0 or 1, depending on your $var

if $var is odd number, ex. (1, 3, 5 ...) it $var & 1 returns 1, otherwise (2, 4, 6) $var & 1 returns 0