# PHP. What does "return($var & 1);" mean?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [callback function return return($var & 1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201134/callback-function-return-returnvar-1)

Example code:

```
<?php
function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return($var & 1);
}

function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return(!($var & 1));
}

$array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
$array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

echo "Odd :\n";
print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));
echo "Even:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array2, "even"));
?>
```

what does this kind of code mean:

```
 return  (x & y)
```

?