# Get input from HTML form as an Array and Check if there is input in the array or not

Tags: php, forms

I input values from HTML form as array like this:

```
 <form method = "post" action = "akf.php">
    Enter Values in Array $a:<br><br>
    <input type="text" name="a[one]" />
    <input type="text" name="a[two]" />
    <input type="text" name="a[three]" />
    <input type="text" name="a[four]" />
    <input type="text" name="a[five]" />
    <br><br><input type="submit" value="Find"><br><br>
 </form>
```

Now I get those input from PHP from the HTML form and display it like this:

```
   $a=$_POST['a'];
   print_r($a);
```

Now without giving any input in the form (ie., An Empty form) if I **submit** the form,

[image]

It should return the message "No Values entered in the Array ".

Note: I want the PHP to return the above message only after I submit the form.

Functions and Syntax's I used to achieve the output:

```
if (empty($a))
{
    echo 'No Values entered in the Array';
}
else
{
    echo 'Array';
}
```

This doesn't work because: I only returns the message "No Values entered in the Array" when the page is loaded newly, when I click the submit button, PHP takes some value as input and returns the message array.

```
$sum = array_sum($a);
if($sum==0)
{
    echo " No Values entered in the Array ";
}
else
{
    echo 'Array';
}
```

This syntax works only when all the inputs are numerical (numbers of any type) . If I enter strings in array through html forms and SUBMIT, it still prints "No Values entered in the Array"
since `array_sum($a);` doesn't count strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns Array because even if you don't enter anything empty strings will be submitted. So if you enter nothing your array will be full of empty strings.

To check if there are only empty strings do:

```
if(!array_filter($a)) {
    echo 'No Values entered in the Array';
}
else {
    echo 'Array';
}
```

[`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will compare all elements to false and if they are false they will be removed. So if all elements in the array are an empty string the returned array will be empty and therefore validated to false.

See also: [Checking if all the array items are empty PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040811/checking-if-all-the-array-items-are-empty-php)

Comment: @sgeems If my or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: if uyou know what does the $var & 1 does please share. Couldn't understand function test_odd($var)
{
return($var & 1);
}

Comment: @sgeems See this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201134/callback-function-return-returnvar-1

Answer (score 0):

```
    you form is:

    <form method = "post" action = "akf.php">
        Enter Values in Array $a:<br><br>
        <input type="text" name="a[]" />
        <input type="text" name="a[]" />
        <input type="text" name="a[]" />
        <input type="text" name="a[]" />
        <input type="text" name="a[]" />
        <br><br><input type="submit" value="Find"><br><br>
     </form>
     no need to add any key.
    php part:
    $values = array_filter($a);

if (!empty($values)) {

echo 'no value';
}else{
echo 'array';
}
```

Comment: I've got problem of pass those input type texts through mysqli_real_escape_string function. Let's assume I used it this way.
`$a=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['a']);` it give error and say `2nd parameter expected as array`

Comment: @SashIKSU as error says it looks like `$_POST['a']` is not an array. try `$_POST` and check and if it works you have to debug and find if `$_POST['a']` is sent as an array or not?

Comment: just now I figure out way to do that. First I put `<input type="text" name="val[]">` ( I have 10 text inputs) to php array. Secondly I call each array element inside the another for loop. In this second for loop I called `mysqli_real_escape_string()` method. It's now OK... Since I'm developing classified ad site I want to know is it okay ?
` 
for($k=0; $k<5; $k++)
            {
                $cleaned_array[$k]=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$values[$k]);
                
            }
`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can try something like:

```
$somethinginarray = false;    

foreach($a as $value) {
    if(!empty($value)) { // trim this one or put more efficient validation
       $somethinginarray = true;
    }
}

if($somethinginarray) echo 'Array';
else echo " No Values entered in the Array ";
```